# Sublime Text 2: Missing "File: Open in Browser" (F12)

Tags: sublimetext2

When I search for "File open in browser" in the Command Palette, I get nothing - i.e. I seem to be missing the "File: Open in Browser" (F12) command.

Actually, I'm missing a whole set of "File: ..." commands from my Command Palette, not just the "File: Open in Browser" command. For example, I'm also missing "File: Move", "File: Copy Path", "File: Close All", etc. See screenshots below.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

[screenshot1](http://cl.ly/image/1z3u0r092s1H) - my sublime text,
[screenshot2](http://cl.ly/PXpI) - friend's sublime text, should look like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands are added by [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) (relevant [source code](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/blob/37da75704bc1968d65957158318a4b283be89291/Commands.sublime-commands#L79-L87)).

I found that using [FindKeyConflict](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts)'s "All Key Maps to Quick Panel" command and then entering "f12" as seen in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend have plugin installed. Install this plugin https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser

Comment: Thanks, but actually, my friend does NOT have that plugin installed. That's the first thing we thought, too. If you compare the 2 screenshots above, I'm missing more "File: ..." commands than just the "File: Open in Browser" command in my Command Palette. For example, I'm also missing "File: Rename" and "File: Copy Path" among others. I think the commands exist, they're just not showing up in my Command Palette for some odd reason that I can't figure out.

Comment: Why isn't View In Browser plugin showing up for me in Sublime Text 2 Install Package?